# Exceptions and StatusCode in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

We have `UseExceptionHandler` (handle Exeptions) and `UseStatusCodePages` (handle StatusCode). Why in ASP.NET Core MVC we using `StatusCodeResult` than just handy extend `Exception`?

Comment: Are you talking about MVC-esque controller with views or a REST Api? ASP.NET Core unifies both of MVC and WebAPI from former frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UseExceptionHandler` is generally used to catch up unexpected errors and preset them in a more friendly manner to the user.

Whereas status codes are more important in REST API to signal the client the success or failure (and specific cause of the failure) of the specific operation.

Controller action should never throw exception  and access a specific resource (i.e. db record) which doesn't exist you should return 404 (not found). When passed data is invalid rest apis return "400 bad request", on success 200. When new resource is created 201 (with "Location" header which contains the url to the new resource, see `CreatedAtAction` method of the controller class).

With views it works differently where you render the error directly into the HTML Code. You can also return status codes with MVC-esque view controllers and handle it with `UseStatusCodePages` (i.e. showing a generic NotFound.cshtml template for resources which don't exist).

Also your question sounds like you want to use exceptions to set status code, this is wrong for a couple of reasons.

1. Exceptions should be (as their name suggest) exceptional; Read: when something unexpected happens. For example if you try to withdraw a negative balance from your bank account and further processing it makes no sense or becomes impossible.

   When you expect an error, you should return a result or handle it differently. For validations you should use Result classes (i.e. `IdentityResult` from ASP.NET Core Identity, which contains a `Success` property and a property which contains a list of error messages in case the operation or the validation fails).
2. Throwing and catching Exceptions is quite expensive, so they should really only be thrown when (as pointed above) something unexpected happens. Not finding a record is nothing unexpected.
3. (Ab)using exceptions for flow control (deciding which code path to execute) is just wrong. That's what `if/switch` and patterns like strategy pattern are for. Exceptions will just make the code unreadable and harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I think this should be in official docs in Q/A